# Menu bar for JavaFX application (Mac OS)

Tags: javafx

working on Macbook.

I'm learning JavaFX and can't understand the concept of main menu.
There are many tutorials on a youtube, showing how to create a menu in JavaFX application. But when I expand my JavaFX application, it's menu does not integrated in main menu of MacOS. I.e. I see JavaFX's menu, and when I move my mouse to the top of the screen, MacOS menu appears separately.

Is it possible to integrate JavaFX menu into MacOS? Like in all other applications - when you see apple icon in the left side, and all other buttons belong to currently open program.

Kind regards,
Gennadiy

Comment: Is [`MenuBar#useSystemMenuBar`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuBar.html#useSystemMenuBarProperty) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.
Thank you.

Comment: java doc is your friend :)